# Using Solspace User extension, can I pass the email address of the user to the 'return' page?

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, registration

In Expression Engine, I have 'Require Member Account Activation?' set to 'Manual activation by administrator', but I would like to send them an email on registration.  I'm using Solspace User for registration ( exp:user:register ), and I was thinking the simplest solution would be to just send an email from the 'return' page.  But they aren't logged in at that point, so I don't have their email address.  Any ideas on a way to get the users email address on the Thank You return page?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no options for the return="" parameter to carry over any data after someone has registered. A query of the exp_members database for the latest email address entered is an approach, but on a popular site with many registration per second, you might inadvertently display the wrong email if someone else registered between sending your form and viewing the thank-you page.

However, in User's Preferences page (CP => Add-ons => Modules => User => Preferences), there is a **Welcome Email** setting where you can create an email notification message when registration is **complete**. The notification email can contain the `{email}` variable, among other variables. Of course, this email would be sent only after the administrator has activated the account.

(User version as of this writing: 3.4.4)